# Ubuntu is also slow for me! how to complain about it?

Tags: 12.04

My system's specs are decent and actually surpasses the documented minimum requirements for Ubuntu 12.04.  But after tons of re-install and un-installs, I've given up on this Linux stuff!
I'm back to using Windows XP and Windows 7, which both works great on my machine.  So disappointed with the hype that "Ubuntu is faster, Ubuntu takes less resources, Ubuntu this, Ubuntu that..." it's all false for me! 
I have a P4 at 2Ghz, 1GB Ram, And a 128-bit Radeon 9550 with 256RAM.  It's not the newest, but its definitely capable - even for playing 3D games!
Yes i've downloaded drivers, updates, and what not, and even tried the 2D desktop, but everything is just SLOW!
And no this is not a rant, rather a real concern.
Why is it so slow, even for simple tasks?
Am I gonna get shut down and be told that Ubuntu is great and all, and that I just have a bad machine and don't know what I'm doing?
If this is so,shouldn't the community change the documented minimum sys. req. on the Ubuntu site, so it won't give people false expectations!
so, please tell me how could i complain it to ubuntu?

Comment: No logs no candies.

Comment: Claiming something is not a rant does not make it not a rant. Proof it is slow please. Have a search for commands to show memory usage and boot diagnoses tool like bootchart.

Comment: Slow how? Where? What drivers did you try? What are the conditions you are running Ubuntu? Have you tried another DE? Can you supply more information?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ubuntu in Gnome Session Fallback. This is another interface faster than default.
You can install this by open a terminal and press:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

Restart system and choose Gnome (no effects) interface. This should work faster than default interface.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the Radeon.  I'm not as immediately familiar with ATI card models as I am with nvidia, so I don't know specifics about your card... But I've certainly been displeased with ATI cards under ubuntu in the past, and the rest of your system specs sound fine.

Unity is a pretty graphically demanding interface, so if the system has real issues with your video card, everything really will seem pretty terrible.  Sorry you didn't have a better experience.

If you do decide to try Ubuntu again, and don't want to update your video card, I would suggest perhaps giving lubuntu - Ubuntu with the LXDE desktop environment - a try.